# Cómo puedo hacer que despues de terminado el primer año en el mes 12, siga con el mes 13 en el año 2?

Tags: bucle-for

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int arancel, duracion_carrera, uf, i, a;
    int caracter_n=165;

    printf("Ingrese valor de arancel: ");
    scanf("%d", &arancel);
    printf("\nIngrese duracion de la carrera: ");
    scanf("%d", &duracion_carrera);
    printf("\nIngrese valor de UF al momento de ingreso: ");
    scanf("%d", &uf);

    float deuda_total = arancel*duracion_carrera/uf*1.15;
    printf("\nDeuda total = %d UF\n", (int)deuda_total);



    for(i=1;i<=duracion_carrera;i++)
    {
        printf("\n| MES\t|\tPago en CLP\t|\t Acumulado en CLP\t|---A%cO %d\n", caracter_n, i); 

///Imprime en pantalla correspondiente a cada año


    for(a=1;a<=12;a++)
        {
            printf("\n  Mes %d:\n", a);
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

En el ciclo for que tengo, se imprime la frase correspondiente a i=1, con i<=duracion_carrera; 
dentro de esta se imprimen los meses que van desde a=1 hasta a<=12, con a++..pero al imprimir la frase correspondiente al año 2, se imprimen denuevo los meses desde el 1 hasta el 12; cómo puedo hacer para que después de imprimir la frase del año 2, siga con el mes 13?.

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Que tal un contador?
int contador = 1;
for(i=1;i<=duracion_carrera;i++)
{
    printf("\n| MES\t|\tPago en CLP\t|\t Acumulado en CLP\t|---A%cO %d\n", caracter_n, i);
    ///Imprime en pantalla correspondiente a cada año
    for(a=1;a<=12;a++)
    {
        printf("\n  Mes %d:\n", contador++);
    }
}
```